# Expected Values of random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given $T$~$exp(1)$ and a group of players.

if $2<=T<=4$ each player wins 5 dollars, if $4<=T<=10$ each player wins 10 dollars if $T>10$ each player wins 10+20 dollars.

Calculate the Expected Value of the won amount of money **per player**.

How can I solve this?

I thought about declaring a new random variable $X$, and now I want to calculate $E(X)$. But the question is how $X$ will be defined... it's related to another random variable $T$ and I never saw such case so I don't know where to start from...

Comment: What is $n$? The number of players?

Comment: @callculus42 just a number, imagine it 5...

Comment: And how many players are involved?

Comment: From what I understand the expected value of the won amount of money per player is $5\cdot P(2\leq T<4)+(10+n)\cdot P(T\geq 4)$

Comment: @callculus42 how the number of players is related... the question about 1 player

Comment: Yes, I've recognized it now. See my previous comment.

Comment: still not clear for me. I was looking for something formal

Comment: What do you mean with "formal"?

Comment: defining new random variable as I suggested...

Comment: I have no idea what the function/meaning of $X$ is. I don´t see any  reason to introduce a new variable.

Comment: @callculus42 you want to calculate Expected value for that new variable....

Comment: Without the definition of X is hard to say what is it.

Comment: @callculus42 BTW your solution is wrong. you didn't add 10*P(t in [4,10])

Comment: Oh yes. And now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random variable $T$ is a function defined on some sample space $S$, and you wish to define another function $X: S \to \mathbb R$ such that
$$X(s) =
\begin{cases}
5, &T(s) \in [2, 4]\\
10, &T(s) \in (4, 10]\\
30, &T(s) \in (10, \infty)\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
.$$
No matter what $S$ is, this completely defines $X$. Since $S$ is not made explicit, you could take $S = \mathbb R$ and $T$ to be the identity; then $X$ is defined explicitly.